# MKMapKit and google tile location

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

i am trying to add some MKOverlays to a MKMapKit. I'll be using our WMS server to fetch tiles based on google's grid location standard and adding them. To make the call, i need to tell our WMS server the google tile (x, y, and zoom level).

i've looked over apple's TileMap sample code which looks like it uses google's tile system.

Does MKMapKit return this information or do i need to derive it from GPS coords?

Comment: Sorry, but your question was not clear to me. Can you please try to explain more? I didn't get what you want.

Comment: for the bounds of my map for a zoom level, i want to figure out which google tiles are in it. google has tiled the plant in 256x256 chunks based on your zoom level. at zoom level 1, you have 1 tile. at zoom level 2, you have 4, zoome level 3 you have 16, etc. each tile has a X and Y for each Z (zoom level).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to derive it yourself.  I found this sample very useful:

https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-MapLayerDemo

Comment: i had looked over the project, but i didn't notice the class "CustomOverlayView.m". reading that over, i think i figured it out: you pass your MKMapRect to mercatorTileOriginForMapRect which gives you the anchor point. you use that to call worldTileWidthForZoomLevel (for both x and y) which returns the tile coordinate at a zoom level?